# unicode values in phpexcel are not exporting

Tags: php, codeigniter, unicode, phpexcel, centos6

I am trying to export unicode values to excel using phpexcel.
The code works perfectly in my localhost but when uploaded to live it is giving junk values.

Framework used : Codeigniter
Server : CENTOS 6.9 , php7, easy Apache 4.

```
public function export_approvedApplication() {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //load our new PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('excel');
    //activate worksheet number 1
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //name the worksheet
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Taluk Excel');
    //make the font become bold
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $output = 'ಹೆಸರು'; 
    //$output = mb_convert_encoding($output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');

    //$output = utf8_encode($output);
    $content_array = array(array('SL No', $output));
    // read data to active sheet
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($content_array);

    $filename = 'ExportEXCEL.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    //save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
    //if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');
    //force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

I have also tried with 'mb_convert_encoding' but was unsuccessfull as it was giving

> Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() 
>   Then I tried installing mbstring , however I was not able to do the same.

Local environment : ubuntu 16 , php7

It would be of great help if anyone could help me with this.
Thank you

Comment: PHPExcel requires all string values stored in cells to be UTF-8... if it isn't being converted to UTF-8 on your server, then check `mb_list_encodings()` to see if the encoding is supported for the conversion that you need to do. If mb_string functions aren't enabled on your server, then you'll need to install/enable them

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding($excel_str, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');` works form me. `$excel_str` is the string including other headers.

Comment: @Mark : Thanks for your prompt reply. I have tried installing mbstring in my server using command "yum install php-mbstring" also tried downloading file and install all gave the same error. 
Error : 
No Match for argument: php-mbstring
No package php-mbstring available.

PLease suggest.

Comment: @GauravRai : Thank you so much. 
It did not work for me. 
As mentioned above in post its giving error stating 
'Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() '

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? What OS is your server? You may need to use `yum install php56-mbstring`, or to specify a repo first `subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms`

Comment: Hey Mark, I already tried as mentioned above, tried installing using 'yum' also tried with repo. 
My server configuration :
'CENTOS 6.9 , php7, easy Apache 4.'

Answer (score 0):

**Issue is fixed.**
@Mark and @Gaurav : Thank you so guys for your suggestions and prompt replies.

As I have mentioned above in my post and in my replies I was not able to render unicode values in my excel export using *PHPEXCEL* .

After googling much and using 'mb_convert_encoding' I found that I have to **enable mbstring extension** . For doing that I tried using terminal (used '*yum install php56-mbstring*' , '*used REPO*', '*tried download*') I dont know why but could not succeed in the same. 
Then I could enable the mbstring only using **WHM login**
I followed the link below

[LINK HERE](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/whm/how-to-install-a-php-extension-using-easyapache-4)

Thank you